# How to detect if heads-up notification is switched off in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-6.0-marshmallow, heads-up-notifications

From API 23, you can toggle the "Allow peeking" switch to the Off position—to no longer receive heads-up notifications for that app.

**Settings > Apps > "Select App" > Notifications.**

[image]

Is there a way to detect this in code?

Comment: have you found some work around for this?

Comment: If your app is legit, why would the user block it?

Comment: @MiguelHincapieC Not yet, unfortunately